# Как поменять фон в select элемента option?

Tags: jquery, html, select

Есть ли возможность менять фон в `select` элемента `option` средствами `jQuery` при наведении мыши?

Comment: Вот всегда на такие вопросы хочется ответить:

 1. Руками.
 2. Да, возможность есть.

Что именно вы делали для этого?

Comment: 1.вот всегда от таких ещё ждёшь и совета поискать в google
2.пытался задавать через css :hover и обращение через селекторы($(select option)), только через .bind("mouseenter"), так как просто $("...").hover() мне не подходит, а ещё пытался гуглить, и вопрос о возможности заодно подразумевал не только сказать "да", но и дать решение, в общем спасибо

Comment: @Sleepless, так ведь не понятно в чём именно у вас возникли проблемы то? Почему .hover не подходит? Или вы думаете что тут телепаты сидят?

Comment: DOM-дерево много раз изменяется, поэтому не катит, элементы создаются и удаляются

Comment: @Sleepless, ну так опишите это в вопросе? Тогда и Вам и Нам будет понятнее в чём суть, и как с этим бороться. Наверное тогда надо при создании вешать .hover ?

Comment: При наведении мыши - способа нет. Для option'ов не в фокусе фон ставится стандартным методом. Если очень надо стилизовать select, воспользуйтесь скриптами типа [jqtransform][1].

[1]: http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот целый набор готовых решений по стилизации тэга select а также `option`: 
[Обзор jQuery-плагинов для стилизации селектов](http://habrahabr.ru/company/aiken/blog/114927/).

Answer (score 1):

Тогда вешайте обработчик не на option, а на select и потом уже добирайтесь до option.

Answer (score 0):

Поиск "кастомный селект", "`select jquery`". Порытся в коде и по ховеру менять класс.